# ffserver configuration file: RTSPOption

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp, ffserver

What are the possible values for RTSPOption in the Stream section of the ffserver configuration file ?

The https://ffmpeg.org/ffserver-all.html#toc-Stream-section mentions the option but no further details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it matters almost 3 years later you can specify RTSP options like this:

```
RTSPOption rtsp_transport tcp
RTSPOption rtsp_flags listen
```